# Chrome geolocation stopped working after an update

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, gps, geolocation

I have recently updated my desktop chrome and mobile android chrome.
Since that I have trouble getting my location. It doesn't work with my website JS geolocation script nor here:
http://html5demos.com/geo

It just says failed. I have tried removing location access privilege and changing to ask but it doesn't work.. Any idea what is the reason for that.

Comment: My site's geolocation works if I access it via localhost, but if I access via local IP (dhcp provided) it doesn't show my position..

Comment: Also found this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=561641  Looks like geolocation API has to come from secure HTTPS origin.. Any idea how can I bypass that on local machine.. My WAMP is on a desktop and I am testing on my android on the same network..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have WAMP accept requests on port 443 and create a certificate in order for the browsers to not complain.  There are detailed instructions here: http://www.lmhproductions.com/31/how-to-setup-ssl-on-wamp/